# Symfony: Search field on table with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I wanna create a table with a search field for every column. I used ajax to send search value to the controller.

My problem is I don't know the type of result that must return the controller (HTML or Json) and how to display the result on my twig table

My JS function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ path('demande_search') }}",
    type: "GET", 
    data: 'filter='+$("#f").val(),
    success: function(data){
        $("#table_id").html(data);
    }
});
```

My table in the twig file:

```
<table id="table_id">
    <tbody>
    {% for demande in demandes %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ demande.did }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My controller that returns the result of search

```
<?php
    /**
     * Lists searched entities.
     *
     * @Route("/search", name="test_search")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT t FROM AppBundle:Test t');
        $categorias = $query->getArrayResult();

        $response = new Response(json_encode($categorias));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should have a look to [dataTables plugin](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjji46Ty8HQAhVFPxoKHaKzBskQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNHbqIifnbX1B1RAxJoziQ5plrvDAQ&sig2=oqZ1GZZktKLbLEcDEtHq8w&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d2s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Controller should output the ready rendered table. Move or copy only the table into a new twig file. Let the Controller create the table and give it back to jQuery:

```
 /**
 * Lists searched entities.
 *
 * @Route("/search", name="test_search")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT t
        FROM AppBundle:Test t'
    );
    $categorias = $query->getArrayResult();

    return $this->render('AppBundle:table.html.twig', ['categorias' => $categorias]);
}
```

Then in your AJAX request you can replace the table with the new table from controller:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ path('demande_search') }}",
    type: "GET", 
    data: 'filter='+$("#f").val(),
    success: function(data){
        $("#table_id").replaceWith(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do not extend any other template in table.html.twig